# How remove a duplicate permanent link in WordPress?

Tags: url, wordpress, links, permalinks

I have two links that show a single post. I need to remove one of them, because I get "Duplicate title tag" warnings in Google Webmaster Tools.

How can I remove a permanent URL from WordPress?

Comment: You say that the URL "redirects."   What type of redirect is it?  302 temporary?  301 permanent?

Comment: I don't use wordpress myself, but its much better to give 301 status to the links that are meant to redirect to another link.  You can even do this at an .htaccess level for faster processing purposes (skips going through PHP)

Comment: no 300 series, it means mention it links to my posts.

Comment: "no 300 series"? How is it _redirecting_? Or is it not redirecting at all and you have two URLs showing the same post?

Comment: It's language issue(English)... sorry for my English language

Comment: @w3d yes, sounds like two URLs going to same post.  Mohsen, can you give us the links so we can see the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have two pages/URLs that show the same post. Ordinarily I would have suggested removing one of these "permalinks" in WordPress - that URL would then return a 404. However, it would seem that these two permalinks have existed for a while(?) and have been indexed and possibly linked to.

So, it might be better (at least in the short term) to 301 redirect one URL to the other in .htaccess (in your document root) using mod_rewrite.

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^path/to/permalink-1 /path/to/permalink-2 [R=301,L]
```

This should come immediately after the existing `RewriteEngine On` directive and before WordPress's own rewrites.